# Regex always returns as NoneType or doesn't find any pattern at all

Tags: python, regex

I got a task to extract/find a pattern in a HTML code and extract/print it.

I am trying to extract it using regex. I am sadly a complete beginner in it.

**Here is the HTML code:** https://pastebin.com/cfvtLpZZ

And here is a part of the code I need to extract:

```
<span>Re: Máte zprávu od ubytování Lanterna Sunny Resort by Valamar<br>  <br>  Excuse me, but I have no pets.Please, I want ground floor, no stairs.Is it possible? Thank you for your answer.Hana Seidlová  </span>
```

Inside of it, I need to get a match between **Re:** and **/span**.

This is a regex pattern I tried to use:  `"^Re:.*span$"`

The code:

```py
import re

HTMLcode = str(input("Enter the code you wanna scrape: "))

def scrape(HTMLcode):
  HTMLscrape = re.search("^Re:.*span$", HTMLcode)

  print(HTMLscrape.group(0))

scrape(HTMLcode)
```

Issue I am having is that HTMLscrape is seen as a `NoneType` by interpreter.

I also tried this code, but I had no luck:

```py
def scrape(HTMLcode):
  HTMLcompile = re.compile("^Re:.*span")

  HTMLsearch = HTMLcompile.search(HTMLcode)

  print(HTMLsearch.group(0))
```

I also tried using [regex 101 website](https://regex101.com) but there it says that no pattern can be found.

What is the issue? Any type of explanation or info/feedback is appreciated!!!

Comment: The caret (`^`) is the "problem“.

Comment: Could you please explain why? Do I need to remove it or?

Comment: The dollar-sign (`$`) is also part of the problem. Both the caret and dollar-sign are what's called "anchors" in regular-expression. The caret tells the matcher to only match the beginning of the string. The Dollar-sign is the opposite, to match only at the end of the string.

Comment: My bad, I accidentally left $ in. It works for now haha. Thanks for info

Comment: It works, but it doesn't stop at the first </span>. It goes from Re to the end of the code (</html>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using https://regex101.com is a good way to find if your regex is good or not. For instance yours is not. `^Re:` means that you're looking for something that starts the **line** with `Re:` and that just after you're looking for **everything**(`.*`) and that ends with `span`.

Isnt'

```py
re.search("<span>Re:(.*?)</span>")
```

more like what you want (starts with `<span>Re:` and capture everything until `</span>`)

Comment: You are talking for the second code I provided or? If yes, I still have the same NoneType issue :/

Comment: Sorry I corrected my answer, it works for the example you gave us `>>> re.search('<span>Re:.*</span>', test_str).group(0)
'<span>Re: M\xc3\xa1te zpr\xc3\xa1vu od ubytov\xc3\xa1n\xc3\xad Lanterna Sunny Resort by Valamar<br>  <br>  Excuse me, but I have no pets.Please, I want ground floor, no stairs.Is it possible? Thank you for your answer.Hana Seidlov\xc3\xa1  </span>'`

Comment: It works, but it somehow doesn't stop at the first </span>

Answer (score 0):

You want lookbehinds and lookaheads to exclude the `<span> Re:` and `</span>`, respectively. You can use this regex for that:

```
(?<=<span>Re:).*(?=</span>)
```

See [regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/CLcjsw/1)

Comment: This is what gets returned for me: <re.Match object; span=(8396, 18793), match=' Máte zprávu od ubytování Lanterna Sunny Resort b>

Comment: looks good, doesn't it? Often the print for `re.match` objects doesn't show the full match if it is too long, try `print(re.findall(r'(?<=<span>Re:).*(?=<\/span>)', text))` to print the full match

Comment: Try it now, without the back-slash in the lookahead. According to regex101 this should work, don't know, why it doesn't stop at `</span>`